# WPF Datagrid DeferRefresh exception

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

This is my DataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="FixedPositionDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding FixedPositionList}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227" Height="128" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontSize="12" CanUserAddRows="False" CellEditEnding="FixedPositionDataGrid_CellEditEnding" CanUserSortColumns="False" PreviewKeyDown="FixedPositionDataGrid_PreviewKeyDown">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEditable}"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Indice" Binding="{Binding Index}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="80"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="%" Width="130">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                <Binding Path="Percentage" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <mynamespace:PercentageValidationRule Min="0" Max="100"/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

And this is the ValidationRule:

```
public class PercentageValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    private int _min;
    private int _max;

    public PercentageValidationRule()
    {
    }

    public int Min
    {
        get { return _min; }
        set { _min = value; }
    }

    public int Max
    {
        get { return _max; }
        set { _max = value; }
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        int percentage = 0;

        try
        {
            if (((string)value).Length > 0)
                percentage = Int32.Parse((String)value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Illegal characters or " + e.Message);
        }

        if ((percentage < Min) || (percentage > Max))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false,
              "Please enter a value in the range: " + Min + " - " + Max + ".");
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

After bad value insertion (that is a value < 0 or > 100 or a string) I see the "!" and the cell has a red border; if I close the window (with any button) and try to reopen it, I have an exception

```
'DeferRefresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction
```

In another DataGrid I have a similar layout of XAML, with DataGridTextColumns
but with no limits and the error does not appear.

I've seen some other questions in SO but no solution works for me